Create a AppScript Email trigger for a Google Sheet that is connected to a Datasource
Can't create an automated email on Appscript each time my Google Sheet connected to a Big Query Table updates, meaning each time a new entry has been detected.
Please find my code below.
// Helper function to get the active sheet
function getActiveSheet(e) {
  if (!e) {
    Logger.log("No event object, this function should be triggered by an event.");
    return null;
  }
  return e.source.getActiveSheet();
}

// Function to send email
function sendEmail(e) {
  if (!e) {
    Logger.log("No event object, this function should be triggered by an event.");
    return;
  }

  var sheet = getActiveSheet(e);
  if (!sheet) {
    Logger.log("No active sheet found.");
    return; // Exit if no sheet is found
  }


  var range = e.range;
  // if (!range) {
  //   Logger.log("No range found.");
  //   return; // Exit if no range is found
  // }
  
  // Define email details
  var recipient = "example@email.com."; // Change this to your email
  var subject = "EOI Google Sheet Updated";
  var message = "Your Sheet link was updated: \n\n";
  
  // Get the updated values
  // var values = range.getValues();
  // for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  //   for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
  //     message += values[i][j] + " ";
  //   }
  //   message += "\n";
  // }
  
  // Send the email
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, message);
}

// Function to create a trigger for the sendEmail function
function createEditTrigger() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmail')
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onChange()
    .create();
}

I'm a DataAnalyst, but I've faced an issue I'm determined to solve.
I have a Google Sheet that I have connected to a Google BigQuery (BQ) Table through a Query.
The Query runs every hour and if a new entry has entered the table, that entry populates into the sheet.
Now I'm trying to use AppScript to create a trigger that sends out an email each time there has been a change in the Google Sheet, meaning a new entry. I struggle mainly with the notification that its Data Sources aren't supported. However throughout my attempts I had various different notifications.
As of now I've commented out the Range part, as AppScript struggles to read Datasource sheets.

An on-edit trigger is only activated by an edit done by a user using the Google Sheets UI. Try using an on-change trigger.

Thank you, I already had it as .onChange, but I just updated the function name to createChangeTrigger.
I'm getting a new error message Exception: This script has too many triggers. Triggers must be deleted from the script before more can be added..
Could that be in relation to how I have my triggers set up?

Each user can have up to 20 triggers on each project. For details on how triggers work and how to delete triggers, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable. If you need further help, please post a new question, as comments are not intended to have extended discussions.

You should alwlays check for other triggers with that same trigger handler function before creating another or you can just delete all of the other triggers that have the same trigger handlerFunction.

There are some onChange triggers that fire on imports but in genreral all of the edit triggers only work for user edits. By the way onChange triggers also have a trigger type look here
